# mmenu slide out menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking for a way to integrate a slideout menu into my website but have failed with various javascript plugins (I'm quite new to web design). I can't seem to get this to work correctly. I recently posted about a side menu which ended up working but was blank on a phone screen. Now I am trying my luck at a mmenu at http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html I have posted my html below and have been trying to fix it for a full day now and still can't get it to work!  You can see what is currently showing up on the website here http://jpst.it/zQtF

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/css/jquery.mmenu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#menu").mmenu({});
            var API = $("menu").data("mmenu")

            $("menu-button").click(function() {
                API.open();
         });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
         <div class="logo"></div>
         <button id="menu-button"><a href="#menu">menu</a></button>
</div>    
    <div class="content">
         <div class="posts">1</div>
         <div class="posts">2</div>
         <div class="posts">3</div>
         <div class="posts">4</div>
         <div class="posts">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">asdfafdsasfsdasfad</div>
    </div>
     <nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your code and without your stylesheets I can't be really sure what your problem is, but I believe your problem starts from the fact that you haven't included jQuery when you include the mmenu javascript file. So switch the lines in your code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/css/jquery.mmenu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/5.3.1/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

That should be enough to make it functional, but remember to include the # symbol in your javascript when you're referencing IDs. As well, remember your semi-colons at the end of all your javascript statements.